# How to put this section on other side of those inputs

Tags: html, css

Hello I tried display:flex, inline, block.
But I can't figure it out how to move those section area other side of those labels and inputs.

I put my whole css,html [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Munkhdelger/hek788yp/) 
and I need some advise to positioning I am some how just cant figure it out.

```
  <label for="tab1">blah blah</label>    
  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">blah blah</label>        
  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">blah blah</label>
```

I leave my whole code in that fiddle and this is picture of my pain i just want to move bottom of that section to there ofc fit [image]

Comment: Where is CSS? try to make a fiddle

Comment: and somehow that jsfiddle dead. just fixed guess

Comment: @CodeLღver sorry i am dull after lot of positioning iykwim

Comment: Do you want the section to be to the right or to above the inputs?

Comment: @Zack to be right sorry my broken english

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hek788yp/1/  ??

Comment: @Ferus7 thanks for replying but i want that section but i trying to look like this http://imgur.com/a/HdmAm

Comment: anyone ? guess i have to dig to it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for replaying i got my answers for digging.
i just changed section display:table-cell

```
main{
display:table;
}
#tab[example content number]:checked ~ #content[example content number] {
 display: table-cell;
}
```

and its parent which is main display:Table if you want [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/Munkhdelger/hek788yp/4/) here it is